# Problem accessing array inside struct

Tags: solidity, events, arrays, struct

Dealing with the code below:

```
contract myContract {

    struct myStruct{
        bytes32 name;
        bool active;
        uint[] changes;
    }

    myStruct[2] myStr;
    uint[] steps;

    Event activatedEvent(uint time);

    function myContract{
        myStr[0] = packStruct('foo', true, steps);
        myStr[1] = packStruct('bar', false, steps);
    }

    function activate(){
        myStruct ms = myStr[0]; 
        ms.changes.push(now);
        activatedEvent(now);
    }
}
```

If I call the `activate()` function, the `activatedEvent` does not get triggered. Anybody knows where I'm wrong? Any help appreciated.

Comment: 1. Have you tried increasing the `gas`?  2. Can you include the output of `getTransactionReceipt` ?

Comment: Also make sure you are watching for the event correctly, you may want to paste your web3 code here as well

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, I increased the gas and now everything works great.

Comment: Please add an answer detailing what you did, and accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

A common reason that a transaction won't run as expected is that it runs out of gas. You can find this out from `web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(transactionHash)`.

If you did run out of gas, then you can send more. For example, if you are using web3, you can set the amount of gas to 1 million with `web3.eth.sendTransaction({ ... , gas: 1000000})`.

Please note~ I take no credit for this answer: the real answer came from user:eth in a comment. I would just like to see this question marked as answered.

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues with the contract. Firstly the `event` should have small 'e' and not a capital 'e' next, function `myContract` should be defined as `myContract()` and lastly `packStruct` was not defined

Below is the updated code.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.4;

contract myContract {

    struct myStruct{
        bytes32 name;
        bool active;
        uint[] changes;
    }

    myStruct[2] myStr;
    uint[] steps;

    event activatedEvent(uint time);

    function myContract() {
        myStr[0] = myStruct('foo', true, steps);
        myStr[1] = myStruct('bar', false, steps);
    }

    function activate(){
        myStruct ms = myStr[0]; 
        ms.changes.push(now);
        activatedEvent(now);
    }
}
```

[image: A screenshot from remix compiler]

You can also use online compiler [remix](https://remix.ethereum.org/#version=soljson-v0.4.10+commit.f0d539ae.js) to compile your code.

Hope it helps!